# Помогите написать функцию для кнопки ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ в таймере

Tags: javascript, функции, таймер

```js
    let counter = 0;

    function timer () {
        counter++;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counter;
        setTimeout("timer()", 1000)
    }

    function but() {
        clearTimeout(counter)

    }

    function cont() {
    
        }


    function reset() {
        clearInterval(counter)
        counter = 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
</head>
 <body onload="timer()">

 <span id="count"></span>

 <button onclick="but()" id="but">Stop</button>

 <button onclick="cont()" id="cont">Continue </button>

 <button onclick="reset()" id="reset">Reset </button>
 


 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала `setTimeout()` первым параметром получает функцию
и возвращает timerId. Воспользовавшись этим мы можем переписать код немного по другому

```js
    let counter = 0;
    let counterTimer = setTimeout(timer, 1000);

    function reDraw() {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counter;
    }
    
    function timer () {
        counter++;
        reDraw();        
        counterTimer = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    }

    function but() {
       clearTimeout(counterTimer);
    }

    function cont() {
       counterTimer = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    }


    function reset() {
        counter = 0;
        reDraw();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
</head>
 <body>

 <span id="count"></span>

 <button onclick="but()" id="but">Stop</button>

 <button onclick="cont()" id="cont">Continue </button>

 <button onclick="reset()" id="reset">Reset </button>
 


 </body>
```

Comment: Что за минус?  можно детали пожалуйста

Comment: убрал: Первый вариант вовсе не работал) А сейчас, единственное: Если много раз подряд тыкнуть continue, таймер будет многократно перезапускаться.

Comment: Согласен да вопрос решается одной переменной, ну или проверкой значения timerCounter

Answer (score 1):

1. Считается плохой практикой передавать строчку кода в setTimeout... `"timer()"`. Вместо этого стоит передать туда ссылку на саму функцию, `setTimeout(timer, 1000);`
2. innerHTML используют при вставке строки HTML. Для обычного текста есть `.textContent`
3. `setTimeout()` - функция. Возвращает число - номер таймера, который он запустил. Именно этот номер потом нужно использовать, чтобы остановить таймер через `clearTimeout(номер)`. Соответственно, нужно куда-нибудь сохранить номер, например, во внешнюю переменную.

```js
let counter = 0;
let timeout = null;

function timer() {  
  counter++;
  document.getElementById('count').textContent = counter;
  
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // Функция не знает, откуда будет запущен следующий таймер.
  // Чтобы каждый раз перед её вызовом отдельно не стирать запущенный Timeout,
  // пусть функция сама это делает на всякий случай.

  timeout = setTimeout(timer, 1000); // Номер текущего таймера записывается в переменную
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function cont() {
  counter--;
  timer();
}

function reset() {
  counter = 0;
  timer();
}
```

```html
<body onload="timer()">

  <span id="count"></span>

  <button onclick="stop()" id="but">Stop</button>

  <button onclick="cont()" id="cont">Continue </button>

  <button onclick="reset()" id="reset">Reset </button>

</body>
```

4. onclick, onload... не стоит использовать дальше учебных примеров: Когда HTML станет большим, а на одну кнопку захочется добавить несколько функций, задолбаетесь искать / редактировать всё. Хорошо бы держать HTML - отдельно, скрипт - отдельно (*см. → querySelector, querySelectorAll, addEventListener*).
5. setTimeout, setInterval не гарантируют точность по времени. `setTimeout(fn, 1000)` означает, что функция будет запущена **не раньше**, чем через секунду. А может немного опоздать. Если важна точность таймера, его привязывают к `new Date();` - т.е. функция всё также тикает через timeout, но время вычисляется и выводится через Date.

Comment: при нажатии на продолжить несколько раз таймер накручивает секунды

Comment: @Bogdan Добавил `counter--;` перед новым вызовом `timer()`

Comment: Огроменное спасибо